# MemoryMappedFile - IOException: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

Hi I've got a problem with a .net process that's throwing the following exception when creating a memory mapped file,

```
System.IO.IOException: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateCore(SafeFileHandle fileHandle, String mapName, HandleInheritability inheritability, MemoryMappedFileSecurity memoryMappedFileSecurity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, MemoryMappedFileOptions options, Int64 capacity)
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, MemoryMappedFileOptions options, MemoryMappedFileSecurity memoryMappedFileSecurity, HandleInheritability inheritability)
```

I've still got a lot of Ram available according to task manager and when it happens my process is at about 3G on a box with 15G of Ram.

My Process is creating and destroying hundreds of these memory mapped files a minute on multiple threads.

Is there some kind of limit I'm running into that I'm not aware of?

My class that's throwing the exception appears to dispose of the memory correctly, it's always in a using statement

```
internal unsafe class VirtuallyBackedMemory : IDisposable
{
    private readonly MemoryMappedViewAccessor _accessor;
    private readonly MemoryMappedFile _file;

    public VirtuallyBackedMemory(string name, long sizeInBytes)
    {
        _file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(name,sizeInBytes, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);

        _accessor = _file.CreateViewAccessor(0, sizeInBytes, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);

        BaseAddress = _accessor.Pointer(0);
    }

    public byte* BaseAddress { get; }

    ~VirtuallyBackedMemory()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_accessor != null)
            {
                if (BaseAddress != null)
                    _accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReleasePointer();

                _accessor.Dispose();
            }

            if (_file != null)
                _file.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Is there some kind of limit I'm running into that I'm not aware of?` - Yes, the [**limit of the paging file**](https://www.howtogeek.com/126430/htg-explains-what-is-the-windows-page-file-and-should-you-disable-it/) in which your memory mapped files are stored. Like the RAM it too has a limited size, so you can't store too much data inside it.

Comment: Show us some evidence that you are using Dispose() correctly.

Comment: The pagefile was set to allow windows to auto manage, I set it manually to 30G to see if that was the issue but I still got the exception

Comment: Any update on this problem? I also just ran into the same issue.

Comment: @WBuck no I limited the number of threads using the memory mapped file and the problem went away.